# ChartJS stock price line chart config with autoscale

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to configure ChartJS to show a stock price line chart with months on an x-axis legend and a price on y.

But want to seed end of week stock closure price, so 4-5 data points per month, depending on the month.

Also is there a way to automatically calculate a current date and automatically build labels on a rolling basis.

So far got this:

```
const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
};

const labels = ['Aug', '', '', '',  'Sep', '', '', '',  'Oct', '', '', '',  'Nov', '', '', '',  'Dec', '', '', '',  'Jan', '', '', '',  'Feb', '', '', '',  'Mar', '', '', '',  'Apr', '', '', '',  'May', '', '', '',  'Jun', '', '', '',  'Jul']

const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Apple stock price',
    data: [141,139,128,133,136,130,136,125,126,128,129,127,122,125,122,122,131,133,131,126,130,131,128,131,131,128,128,126,128,127,133,130,137],
    fill: false,
    borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
    tension: 0.5
  }]
};
```

But looks like I need somehow to configure the logarithmic scale for the y-axis as well as better distribute/map weekly prices to months.

Found several examples/answers here but a lot of them are for the question 5-10 years old, so maybe in a newer version this task can be done easier.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work

```
    var historicalprices = await yahooFinance.historical("AAPL", { period1: '2019-01-01', interval: '1mo' })
    var prices = historicalprices.map(historicalprice => ({ [historicalprice.date.toLocaleDateString('en-us', { year: "numeric", month: "short" })]: Math.round(historicalprice.adjClose) }))
const data = {
    labels: prices.map(x => Object.keys(x)).flat(),
    datasets: [{
        data: prices.map(x => Object.values(x)).flat(),
        fill: false,
        borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
        tension: 0.1
    }]
}
```